# $v_{GW}$ near a star

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

The Einstein field equations may be written as
$R_{\mu \nu }-{\tfrac {1}{2}}R\,g_{\mu \nu }={8\pi G}T_{\mu \nu }$. At a very large distance from massive bodies one can neglect $T_{\mu \nu }$ and linearize the rest of the equation. Then it follows that a GW
exists, which propagates at the speed of light when the amplitude is small. Both requirements are certainly not met in the vicinity of the source (a binary star or a pulsar).

Question 1: Do we know of a solution to the field equations near large masses?

Question 2: Is the time dependence taken into account because the stars of the binary system move?

Question 3: Can the mass of the Sun be neglected when receiving GW here on Earth? In other words: Does the linear approximation with $v_{GW}=c$ apply here?

Answer (score 0):

The vacuum field equations apply everywhere in vacuum, that is outside a ball where the transport of massive and electromagnetic energy and momentum density, denoted as T, is zero.

The quasi-stationary, periodic wave near-field  of binary star system has the frequency of the revolution of masses, unit 1/year, wavelength 1 lightyear.

Both masses are positive, the rotation of two positive 1/r-fields with center rotating on a circle  yields the rotating quadrupol near field. The quasistatic rotating near field falls off as $r^{-4}$ into space, as for two antiparallel electric dipols.

Generally the near field zone ends after some wavelength.

Outside of a sphere of the dimension of a solar system the wave is pure radiation outward with an energy density per m^2 decay by 1/r^2 in the same way as for any radiation field with constant outward energy transport over constant-time spheres of any radius with constant time spatial area growing a $r^2$. The static monopol field does not change the surface area of spheres, it changes radial distances time scales affecting wavelength and frequancy of the outgoing wave.

Comment: Ok, that's reminiscent of the near field around the antenna in electromagnetic waves, but it doesn't answer my question: How large is $v_{GW}$ at a distance of 1 AU from the binary system? How large is $v_{GW}$ at a distance of 5 AU from the binary system?